# How to bring the value of "val" to the bottom?

Tags: python, gtk

The following is my code and i want to bring the variable "val" to the bottom, How can to it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gtk

class ScaleButton:
def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(100, 100)
    scalebutton = gtk.ScaleButton(gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU, float(0), float(2.5),         float(0.025), (gtk.STOCK_ZOOM_FIT, gtk.STOCK_ZOOM_FIT))
    scalebutton.set_value(float(0.4))
    val = scalebutton.get_value()
```

The variable "val has to be printed in the bottom

```
    window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
    scalebutton.connect("value-changed", self.value_changed)

    window.add(scalebutton)
    window.show_all()

def value_changed(self, scalebutton, value):

    valu = scalebutton.get_value()
    print valu
    print val
```

*is there any way to print these two variables in a single*

```
ScaleButton()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: if val is always 0.4 then print (0.4, valu) comes to mind

Comment: Please make your question clearer, it's really difficult to understand what you want: The phrases "is there any way to print these two variables in a single" and "How to bring the value of val to the bottom" do not not mean anything. You'll have to explain more or add examples of the result you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could set the variable val to global.  `global val`  You'd have to set that at the beginning and then call it as global everywhere you wanted to use it with that value.

Comment: Using `global` is considered bad practice, _especially_ within a class, because if you create another instance of the class, the `val` from the first class is overshadowed by the `val` from the second class. Simply replace all the instances of `val` with `self.val`. That way, it can be accessed throughout the class, and won't interfere with any other instances of the class.